# Django cannot import module after deployment

Tags: python, django

I transferred my Django project to another server and did the following steps.

- Took a list with installed python modules on my virtual environment with **pip freeze > requirements.txt**
- Transfered my project folder with **scp** (from one server to another)
- Created a virtual environment with **mkvirtualenv**
- Installed the requirements with **pip install -r requirements.txt** in my virtual environment
- Double-checked the modules, one by one, to verify they all are in the same version
- Tried to **./manage.py runserver** and **./manage.py runworker** and got "**cannot import name patterns**"

So, I have the same modules installed, at the same version, with the same version of Django and it throws me an import error about "patterns" module, the same time that it is working correctly on the previous server with exactly the same modules installed.

I am struggling for three days now, I also did the whole process from the beginning to make sure I don't forget anything. Any direction will be totally appreciated.

EDIT: "patterns" refers to urls.py's patterns.

**The error:**

```
(amanet_venv) [kourtdim@web640 main_folder]$ amanet/manage.py runserver
/home/kourtdim/lib/python2.7/floppyforms/__init__.py:21: UserWarning: Unable to import floppyforms.gis, geometry widgets not available
  "Unable to import floppyforms.gis, geometry widgets not available")
/home/kourtdim/lib/python2.7/floppyforms/__init__.py:21: UserWarning: Unable to import floppyforms.gis, geometry widgets not available
  "Unable to import floppyforms.gis, geometry widgets not available")
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x33592a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 44, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kourtdim/main_folder/amanet/amanet/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kourtdim/.virtualenvs/amanet_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

Comment: do you have `patterns` module (that you write) in project?

Comment: @Aiven it's from urls.py, which is in place

Comment: You are running the manage.py command in the virtual environment?

Comment: @JonClements yes, exactly

Comment: @CDoc can you include the urls.py file and console error in your question?

Comment: can you show us `urls.py`?

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis editing the question now. (I'm Greek too)

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: @Aiven (1, 10, 0, u'final', 1)

Comment: and on server you also have 1.10?

Comment: @Aiven yes, sure. In both of them, the working one and the new one.

Comment: @CDoc okay - my next guess is that you've installed the necessary python packages, but the system itself is missing the underlying libraries  that floppyforms (which in turn depends on GeoDjango which depends on system libraries to be installed) are missing. Do you remember "apt-get install"ing (or whatever) libraries on the previous system? eg: Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/

Comment: @JonClements the same error appears after i do **pip install -U django-floppyforms** - is there anything else i should do?

Comment: @CDoc have a look at the link above and check you've followed the instructions there

Comment: @JonClements i will try that and i will inform you. Thank you!

Comment: @JonClements although i didn't install anything like that on the previous server, i tried it to the new one and it still fails to import "patterns" from urls.py

Comment: starting from django1.10 `django.conf.url` doesn't contain `patterns`, it just uses native `list` for `urlpatterns`. I recommend you to update your project to 1.11 or 2+

Comment: @Aiven which kind of hints that the assertion the virtual environments are using the same versions of packages isn't necessarily correct :)

Comment: @Aiven true, i've read about it but how is it even possible to have django1.10 on the working server without any problems? The project is up and running right now on the previous server with the exact same versions...

Comment: can you show us `requirements.txt`?

Comment: i've installed django (1, 10, 0, u'final', 1) on python2.7 and python3.6, both yield that `patterns` is missed. My last bet is that your run your working server in different environment with django1.9-

Comment: I think there is issue with virtualenvwrapper try restalling virtualenvwrapper

Comment: You should use Python 3. Django no longer supports Python 2.